# Can't build "HelloWorld" project

Tags: android, cordova

I've installed PhoneGap the first time and trying to build the "HelloWorld" Project but it fails ever time. Even if I only create a new project, add Android as platform and directly after it trying to build.

I use the following commands:
- cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
- cd hello/
- cordova platform add android
- phonegap local build android

Error:
http://pastebin.com/VgKTUnfp

Answer (score 0):

Cordova for Android requires the Android SDK which could be installed on OS X, Linux or Windows operation system. See the Android SDK's System Requirements.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was system-specific - it took me many hours to find a fix it:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```